# running android emulator from worklight

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I wish to run an application on android virtual device (I've created it). I right-click on the 
Android project (which was created after I added the android environment) and choose "Run as Android Application". The emulator launches but it remains just a black window (and I wait a lot, nothing happens). Console writes "Build successful" and that's it. What might be the problem? API level is 18 (4.3). Platform Windows 7. Thanks.

Details: created a project, added hybrid application, added adaptors, deployed and run multiple times (just in browser), installed android in eclipse, added android environment, added AVD (had some old ones that didn't work, deleted them and created a new one following advises here).

Comment: Which API level did you choose for you AVD? What is the API level you've set in AndroidManifest.xml? What is the Build target you've selected for the Android project?

Comment: It's 18 (4.3) in all the places you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the problem is with your Android emulator.

First, can you start the emulator by itself, and see it work properly? You can start it from AVD itself. The emulator usually takes a long time to start, especially if you are running the ARM emulator instead of the x86 one.

If that works, can you run an empty Android app? You can go to File - New Project - Android Application Project, and after you create it, you should be able to run it and see an empty application.

If that works, can you try with an empty Worklight application? That way we can see if it is your specific application or something to do with Worklight.